# Error in Mongoose Installation

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

While installing mongoose, I am facing this error. I have also increase the space but still not fixed the problem.

Error -

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Can you check with other modules, is the same error occurred?

Comment: Your E: disk is still running out of space. How much space is left on it?

Comment: Thank you for replying abdulbarik. There is no problem with other modules.

Comment: Thank you for replying robertklep. Around 600 mb of space is left in E drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem related to last npm release of mongoose (4.10.3).

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225425/5156280) answer to a similar question
and this github [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5303).

You can temporarily downgrade your mongoose package to previous version until a new plubished release (or make some more space in your drive if you want to use this one specifically).

Comment: Thank you TGrif for your help. I installed the previous version of the mongoose. Thanks a lot.