# Mongoose NPM package is HUGE and contains logs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

I'm using mongoose to connect to a mongo database.

I'd like to understand why `node_modules/mongoose` goes over 1gb...
And when I check what's inside, I get 3 huge folders (31000, 31001, 31002) with what seems to be logs, even with a fresh reinstall..

```
$ rm -Rf node_modules/mongoose
$ npm i mongoose
$ ls -al node_modules/mongoose/tools/31000/journal
total 614400
drwxr-xr-x   5 florian  staff        170 May 28 08:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  27 florian  staff        918 May 28 08:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 florian  staff  104857600 May 24 21:27 WiredTigerLog.0000000001
-rw-r--r--   1 florian  staff  104857600 May 24 08:06 WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
-rw-r--r--   1 florian  staff  104857600 May 24 08:06 WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002
```

What is it ? How do I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `mongoose@4.10.3` was published to the NPM repository containing those database files (which of course shouldn't have happened).

I've contacted the author, but for now, you can use the previous version:

```
npm i mongoose@4.10.2
```

Comment: Thanks ! Was driving me crazy ! I forked the repo and used the git address when install the pack for now. Will add a comment on the issue you created to give some more insights.

Answer (score 3):

mongoose@4.10.4 is already out and doesn't have 900mb of bonuses

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest version of Mongoose. For that clear NPM cache on your local machine:

```
npm remove mongoose
npm cache clean
npm install mongoose
```